# Read Data value from sql server in every x seconds from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to view SQL Server data on an asp.net page. The values in SQL Server will change dynamically.  I've created a timer thread to fetch the data from SQL Server

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    myTimer.AutoReset = true;
    myTimer.Interval = 3000;
    DisplayTimeEvent(null, null);
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => DisplayTimeEvent(sender, e));
    myTimer.Start();
}
protected void DisplayTimeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SCADASTATION\\WINCC;Initial Catalog=LIVEDATA;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=root");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = sc;
    sc.Open();
    SqlDataReader read = (null);
    com.CommandText = ("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DATATABLE1 ORDER BY 1 DESC ");
    read = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (read.Read())
    {
        TAG1.Text = read[1].ToString();
        TAG2.Text = read[2].ToString();
        TAG3.Text = read[3].ToString();
    }
    sc.Close();
}
```

But I failed on this since it does refresh the value of textbox. also I failed on Sleep(3000) function. right now I'm refreshing the values from HTML page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2" />
```

I need to refresh only textbox values rater than refresh entire web page. Is there any better solution for this problem? or did I miss anything in my code?

Comment: The simplest way is to use Ajax in the page to poll a script for changes, parse the response and update the DOM

Comment: @AlexK. Can you sent any weblinks to read about that, I'm new to .net. any examples

Comment: Using a Timer on server side is a bad idea, you should try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324987/how-to-make-ajax-timer-decrement-properly-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

write your logic to below event

```
   protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // your logic
    }
```

and  set
              myTimer.Interval = 3000;

Comment: no It does not worked, tried already with parameters. didn't refresh the values